# Delay in .at Domain Name Registration?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar, top-level-domains

I noticed at http://101domain.com that there's a three (3) day delay in registering new .at TLD domains. Any idea why this is? Is it just back-end processing/approval? Has anyone had it go sooner?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing I can find in the [nic.at terms/legal docs](http://www.nic.at/en/service/legal_information/) that mentions a wait period. It's possible that they're just slow, and the 101domain mention is intended as informative, not a "requirement."
Why don't you just ask them? They have chat support available.